# Simple Selectable with Jquery

Tags: jquery, css

I have just 3 divs all with a background color of blue.

I need jQuery to make each box selectable.
When the box is clicked/selected, jQuery should add class .selected with a different background color to red. All the others not selected should change back to blue when clicking another div.

Here's the css

```
.block {
    width: 300px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: blue;
    color:white;
    margin-top:5px;
}

.selectable {
    background: red;
}
```

Here's the html

```
<div class="block">
    Some stuff here
</div>

<div class="block">
    Some stuff here
</div>

<div class="block">
    Some stuff here
</div>
```

​How do I do it with jQuery?
Here's all the actual [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3PEqC/2/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3PEqC/6/)**.

```
$('.block').click(function() {
    $('.block').removeClass('selectable');
    $(this).addClass('selectable');
});​
```

Comment: On second thought, this one did it for me! Awesome! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [siblings method](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) if the elements are siblings:

```
$(".block").on("click", function() {
    $(this).addClass("selectable").siblings().removeClass("selectable");
});
```

Or:

```
var $blocks = $(".block").on("click", function() {
    $blocks.removeClass("selectable");
    $(this).addClass("selectable");
});
```

Comment: Now this is interesting. siblings of a li?

Comment: @wolverene I don't understand what your question is - Can you please explain? (`Now this is interesting. siblings of a li?`)

Comment: @NULL sorry, please disregard that question. As I still need to understand fully what the siblings method is. Still learning stuff. But now I'm beginning to see how truly amazing jquery is and it's unlimited potential. I have learned so much from this post! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
$('.block').click(function() {
    $('.selected').removeClass('selected')
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

My approach would be unselecting all other divs on click, then toggling the clicked one (to allow unselecting as well):

```
​$('.block').click(function() {
    $('.block').not($(this)).removeClass('selectable');
    $(this).toggleClass('selectable');
});​​​​​
```

Updated [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/3PEqC/7/).

Answer (score -1):

The code for this is super simple.

```
$('.block').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass('selected'); // if it has the class, it will take it away, if it doesn't have it, it will add it.
});
```

Comment: `-1` for oversimplification.. doesn't change other divs, as required by OP